# Enable Oracle Database options in an existing database

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I want to enable Oracle Real Application Testing option in my existing database, but I couldn't find the way to do that using Oracle Universal Installer (OUI) or Database Configuration Assistant (DBCA). Do I have to reinstall the Oracle software in order to enable the options that I didn't choose to install during Oracle software installation?

The version of the Oracle Database installed is 11.2.0.3.

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't have to reinstall the Oracle software. According to the section ["Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.1) New Features"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24321/whatsnew.htm#BGGBHDFG) in the Database Installation Guide 11g Release 2:

> Oracle Universal Installer no longer provides the custom installation
>   option of individual components. Use the `chopt` tool, a command-line
>   utility that is located in the `ORACLE_HOME/bin` directory, to configure
>   the database options.

For example, to enable Oracle Real Application Testing, you would first shut down your database, and then issue `chopt` as follows:

```
chopt enable rat
```

For more information on how to enable and disable other database options with `chopt`, consult ["Enabling and Disabling Database Options"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24321/post_inst_task.htm#CHDFEIJF) section in the Database Installation Guide 11g Release 2.